# Is there a font face in which all glyphs are identical?

Tags: fonts

As strange as it seems, I am looking for a font in which all characters look exactly the same.

The goal is to obfuscate the text of passwords generated on http://enlargeyourpassword.com to the casual observer. At the same time, the user must be able to select one of the generated passwords and copy it or drag it to a password input on another page.

This should be a font which contains essentially only 1 character regardless of what is typed; the same symbol should be associated with every character.

I do not need a Pro font with support for lots of Unicode characters, the generated passwords contain only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always make your own....

[Myscriptfont.com](http://www.myscriptfont.com/)

Download the template, fill it out, upload, and it generates a ttf for you. You can use other apps like Photoshop or Illustrator to fill out the form. It doesn't have to have handwritten characters.

Comment: You are right, I accept your answer :) I tried myscriptfont.com and it actually took me less time to create the font than to continue looking for an existing font matching the requirement. The process was a bit tedious though, and after the upload, the tool complained that the dimensions of the picture (which I kept unchanged when converting the PDF to a PNG) were too small for a high resolution scan, and the character did missed some parts I had drawn. I will look for another tool to create the font.

Comment: I agree, this site has issues.  It's really designed around using hand written characters.  The spacing in the template is imprecise and the resulting font will have alignment issues.

Answer (score 8):

My gods, someone actually has a use for [Squiggle font!](http://squigglefont.tripod.com/)

Comment: Good catch! Two questions though: 1) are the glyphs identical (or random?). It seems from the sample that different shapes of waves are included in each font. 2) does the font license allow use in @font-face?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea; this was just one of those things I dimly remembered from some font catalog or website ages ago and I was delighted to find that it was still out there somewhere.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Thanks, that was close enough :) I will create my own font, with a stylized password star and publish it in Creative Commons in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Let us know when you do; I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: "Only" $29.95? I'd expect that to be free, lol. Also, was that site really designed in 2007 like the copyright notice seems to indicate? :S

Comment: @flarn2006 I have no idea, but it certainly looks that way.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers pointed to websites where you can make your own font.

Marc's answer pointed to FontStruct, where I found this font that does what the OP was looking for:

http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1069549/write_your_password_with_this_font

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own font using FontStruct!

[FontStruct](http://fontstruct.com)

Very, very easy and you could make it look however you like.

---

Can you obfuscate the text another way? You could place a div on top that blocks it (and uses `pointer-events:none` to allow the clicks through). Or, you could set the text's opacity to 0... or probably many other things. You can probably even highlight the text using Javascript and just ask the use to press command-C / control-C to copy the password, without the div even showing at all.

Many, many options!

Please note that you can't use Javascript to access the clipboard in most modern browsers, so that's not an option. [More discussion about copying to clipboard with Javascript here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome).

Comment: Using a div with pointer-events:none works in Firefox, nice trick. Sadly, this is not supported in IE up to version 9 and neither in Opera up to version 11. http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: Setting the opacity to 0 is simpler and better supported. The lack of feedback is a bit disturbing though, because nothing gets displayed when passwords are generated.